# Zohar - the importance of creating baalei teshuva

Tags: zohar, baal-teshuva

Someone mentioned to me that the Zohar mentions the importance of making baalei teshuva. There’s a story that expresses this from the Satmar Rebbe in the hakdama to his Peirush on eichah, but I don’t see it in the Zohar. Anyone know a source?

Comment: אשר עשו בחרן. שֶׁהִכְנִיסָן תַּחַת כַּנְפֵי הַשְּׁכִינָה; אַבְרָהָם מְגַיֵּר אֶת הָאֲנָשִׁים וְשָׂרָה מְגַיֶּרֶת הַנָּשִׁים, וּמַעֲלֶה עֲלֵיהֶם הַכָּתוּב כְּאִלּוּ עֲשָׂאוּם

Comment: Someone also recently mentioned this to me. But you weren't there so I assume it's a coincidence and it wasn't the same person at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

זוהר כרך ב (שמות) פרשת תרומה
וקודשא בריך הוא רמיז לד' משריין עלאין ונטלין לההוא דיוקנא ואזלין עמיה ואיהו עאל לע' עלמין גניזין דלא זכי בהו בר נש אחרא בר אינון גניזין לאינון דעבדי נפשיהון דחייביא, **ואלמלי הוו ידעי בני נשא כמה תועלתא וזכו (גרמי לצדיקיא) וזכאן בגינייהו כד זכו להון, הוו אזלו אבתרייהו ורדפי לון כמאן דרדיף בתר חיין**, מסכנא זכי לבני נשא בכמה טבאן בכמה גניזין עלאין לאו איהו כמאן דזכי בחייביא, מה בין האי להאי אלא מאן דאשתדל בתר מסכנא איהו אשלים חיין לנפשיה וגרים ליה לאתקיימא וזכי בגיניה לכמה טבאן לההוא עלמא, ומאן דאשתדל בתר חייביא איהו אשלים יתיר, עביד לסטרא אחרא דאלהים אחרים דאתכפיא ולא שלטא ואעבר ליה משלטנותיה, עביד דאסתלק קודשא בריך הוא על כורסי יקריה, עביד לההוא חייבא נפשא אחרא, זכאה חולקיה:

פירוש הסולם לזוהר - שמות פרשת תרומה מאמר תלת גוונין- גו שלהובא
[אות נ] וקב"ה רמיז לד' וכו': והקב"ה רמז לד' מחנות מלאכים עליונים, ולוקחים צורה ההיא והולכים עמה, והוא נכנס לע' עולמות גנוזים, שלא זכה בהם אדם אחר זולתו כי אלו הגנוזים הם לאותם שעושים נפשות הרשעים. **ואם בני אדם היו יודעים כמה תועלת וזכות זוכים בשבילם כשמזכים אותם בתשובה, היו הולכים אחריהם ורודפים אותם, כמי שרודף אחר החיים.** 
 [אות נא] מסכנא זכי לבני וכו': עני מזכה בני אדם בכמה טובה בכמה אוצרות עליונים, והוא אינו כמי שזיכה את הרשעים. מה בין זה לזה. אלא מי שמשתדל ועושה צדקה עם העני, הוא משלים חיים לנפשו, וגורם לו להתקיים וזוכה בשבילו כמה טובה בעולם ההוא. ומי שמשתדל אחר הרשעים להחזירם בתשובה, הוא משלים יותר, כי עושה לצד האחר דאלהים אחרים שיכנע ולא ישלוט, ומעביר אותו מממשלתו, עושה שהקב"ה מתעלה על כסא כבודו, עושה לאותו רשע נפש אחר, אשרי חלקו.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Since this site is meant for English readers, a translation would do much to increase the usefulness of this answer